Evaluate $\int_{0}^1x^n\ln(x)^mdx$
$$
\mbox{I have to evaluate the integral}\quad
\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\ln^{m}\left(x\right){\rm d}x
$$
where I do not have much information about $n,m$, so I suppose they are natural numbers.

In that case, I have tried the substitution $u = \ln\left(x\right)$ but I think this is not the right path.
Guess I have to relate it to some kind of Gamma function but I am
stucked.


Duplicate candidates: Find $\displaystyle \int_0^1x^a \ln(x)^m \mathrm{d}x$, Evaluating $\int _0 ^1 x^k(\ln x)^m dx$ for integer $k$ and $m$

That substitution looks good for me. Notice that, doing that, you get $$\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{(n+1) u} u^{m} \mathrm{d}u$$
If you set $u=-v$, then
$$(-1)^{m}\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-(n+1) v} v^{m} \mathrm{d}v$$
Setting $v=x/(n+1)$, you have arrived at the $\Gamma$-function. Up to some prefactors, you should then get $\Gamma(m+1)$ here. Assuming you have natural numbers, you can even make sense of $\Gamma(m+1)=m!$. But be sure first, that the integral converges first.
Sorry, my first ever text on stackexchange. It will get better :)

Welcome to Math.SE! Great first answer!

@Thank you for your answer!

One question, when you change $u=-v$ shouldn't there be a $(-1)^{m+1}$? for the change in the differential

Well, we use one minus sign to change the integration order.

Substituting $u=-ln(x)$ you get $(-1)^m\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-(n+1)u}u^mdu$. You can do this in two steps if you think it's easier. Not let $v=(n+1)u$. Then we get $\frac{(-1)^m}{(n+1)^{m+1}}\int^\infty_0 e^{-v}v^mdv=\frac{(-1)^m m!}{(n+1)^{m+1}}$.

Thanks and nice answer!

One question, when you change $u=-ln(x)$ shouldn't there be a $(-1)^{m+1}$? for the change in the differential

@MiguelCG The extra factor of (-1) generated from the change of variables went into flipping the boundary on the integral.
